# According to Hindu scripture where is the center of universe?

Tags: scripture, astrology

Center of universe is Dhruv nakshatra (Pole Star) with simshumaradhi as antaryami.. that is why it stays in the same place. it wont appear to move even though every thing else around it move. Please provide scriptural reference if any.

Comment: Mount Meru probably?

Comment: Mount meru is axis of earth which Mt Kailash in tibet i believe but im asking about universe @Lazylubber

Answer (score 1):

I checked everywhere.

I could find only two answers to your question.

This isn't the answer you are expecting, but is the one which is available in accordance with the Hindu scriptures.

1. Mount Meru is the center of the Universe.

> The Christians believe that the earth was the center of the universe. Hindus believe that Mount Meru, a golden mountain, is the center of the universe. Mount Meru is the most sacred object in the universe because it supports the heavens and the gods.

2. Mahavishnu's Navel is the center of the universe.

> As per our Puranas, the stalk of the lotus flower emerges from the navel of Lord Vishnu . It is just NOT a simple flower –but an amazing allegory–  the lotus “seed-pod”, which is symbolically equivalent to the golden Mount Meru, the axis-mundi of the universe. Lotus is the symbol of Hinduism, as a lotus with a supple long stalk emanated from the navel of Lord Vishnu.